# Azure Error, The Data Protection Operation was unsuccessful

Tags: .net, azure, owin

I got error when using OWIN and published in Azure.

[image]

when i search the problem is in IIS where LoadUserProfile is False

is there any solution for this? or any setting in Web.Config to change LoadUserProfile be True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i'm using like this

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, token, vm.NewPassword);

Then i Change like this
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user.Id);
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user.Id, vm.NewPassword);

I hope my source can help everybody
Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a look at [this blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites-4/). The following is a snippet:

> WIF protects cookies using DPAPI and the user store. When your app is hosted in IIS, its AppPool must have a specific option enabled (“Load User Profile”) in order for DPAPI to access the user store. **In Windows Azure Web Sites, that option is off (with good reasons, it can exact a heavy toll on memory)** and you can’t turn it on. But hey, guess what: even if you could, that would be a bad idea anyway. The default cookie protection mechanism is not suitable for load balanced scenarios, given that every node in the farm will have a different key: that means that a cookie protected by one node would be unreadable from the other, breaking havoc with your Web app session.

If you want to run your application to Azure Web App, please try the workarount that blog mentioned.